# How could I automatically delete closing html tag when removing opening one in VSC?

Tags: html, visual-studio-code

Just want closing html tag to be removed when I delete the opening one. In VSC.

Probably AutoCompleteTag or basic VSCode intruments has this setting. Don't know.

For example if I delete opening  closing one still exist in code. Don't like it :(

And when I try to remove closing first I get something like this:

```html
<tagname classes...>
</tagname>
```

....removing closing tag....

```html
< classes...>
```

Comment: have a look at the Emmet command: **Remove Tag**

Answer (score 0):

I use vscode, I don't think it has this function, and it shouldn't be too hard to just remove the opening and closing elements manually.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).